# Proper/Title Case a Column with Exceptions table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert a column which is in upper case to proper case but with exceptions like certain acronyms, abbreviations. I am following the below code to implement that. But looks like this will be an ongoing process and so, I want to create a table with the exceptions  in order to make it easy to clean the data and I want to be able to call the exceptions table from the function. It would be great if anyone can help me with any codes they have which is similar to this or any ideas on how to implement it.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Business_ProperCase]
     (@Text AS VARCHAR(8000)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    -- declare some variables 
    DECLARE @Reset BIT; DECLARE @Ret VARCHAR(8000); DECLARE @i INT; 
    DECLARE @c0 CHAR(1); DECLARE @c1 CHAR(1); DECLARE @c2 CHAR(1); 
    DECLARE @CaseLen INT; 
    DECLARE @CaseExceptions VARCHAR(8000); 
    DECLARE @CaseValue VARCHAR(8000); 

    -- Set some default values 
    SELECT @Reset = 1, @i=1, @Ret = ''; 

    -- only apply if all characters are already in uppercase 
    IF (UPPER(@Text)=@Text COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) 
         BEGIN 

                 -- add a leading and trailing space to indicate word delimiters (bol & eol) 
                 SET @Text = ' ' + @Text + ' '; 

                 -- cycle through each character, 
                 -- if non-alpha, uppercase next alpha character. 
                 -- if alpha then lowercase subsequent alphas. 
                 WHILE (@i <= LEN(@Text)) 
                         SELECT 
                                 @c0=SUBSTRING(@Text,@i-2,1), @c1=SUBSTRING(@Text,@i-1,1), @c2=SUBSTRING(@Text,@i,1), 
                                 @Ret = @Ret + CASE WHEN @Reset=1 THEN UPPER(@c2) ELSE LOWER(@c2) END, 
                                 @Reset = CASE 
                                                                                             WHEN @c0 = ' ' AND @c1 = 'M' AND @c2 = 'c' THEN 1 

                                                 WHEN @c0 = ' ' AND @c1 IN ('D', 'I', 'O') AND @c2 = '''' THEN 1 


                                                 WHEN @c2 LIKE '[a-zA-Z'']' THEN 0               -- Apply LOWER to any character after alphas or apostrophes 
                                                ELSE 1                                                                  -- Apply UPPER to any character after symbols/punctuation 
                                         END, 
                                 @i = @i +1 

                 -- add a trailing space in case the previous rule changed this. 
                 SET @Ret = @Ret + ' '; 

                 -- custom exceptions: this search is case-insensitive and will 
                 -- replace the word to the case as it is written in the list. 
                 -- NOTE: this list has to end with a comma! 
                 SELECT @i=0, @CaseLen=0, 
                         @CaseExceptions = 'ABS,LLC,MD,MBA,MA,

--Want to create a table for these exceptions and call them from this function 
                 -- Loop through exception cases 
                 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @CaseExceptions, @i+1)>0 
                         BEGIN 
                                 -- get the delimited word 
                                 SET @CaseLen = CHARINDEX(',', @CaseExceptions, @i+1) - @i 
                                 SET @CaseValue = SUBSTRING(@CaseExceptions, @i, @CaseLen) 

                                 -- replace it in the original text 
                                 SET @Ret = REPLACE(@Ret, ' '+@CaseValue+' ', ' '+@CaseValue+' ') 

                                 -- get position of next word 
                                 SET @i = CHARINDEX(',', @CaseExceptions, @i+@CaseLen) +1 
                         END 

                 -- remove any leading and trailing spaces 
                 SET @Ret = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Ret)); 

                 -- capitalize first character of data irrespective of previous rules 
                 SET @Ret = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Ret,1,1)) + SUBSTRING(@Ret,2,LEN(@Ret)); 

         END 
    ELSE 
     BEGIN 
                 -- return the string unaffected if it is not in uppercase 
                 SET @Ret=@Text 
         END 

    RETURN @Ret 
 END
```

Comment: Exactly HOW is this not working?

Comment: This is working perfectly fine, Marc. But I want to make the exceptions in the form of a table where I can have all the exceptions at one place or even modify it to include spelling mistakes in the column and use replace or something from the table. I am not sure how to go ahead with that.

Comment: You need to be able to pick out the words rather than just single characters. Iterate over words with something like `set @nextpos = charindex(' ', @text, @lastpos)` and `set @word = substring(@text, @lastpos + 1, @nextpos - @lastpos - 1)`. Then check to see if `@word` is in your exceptions list.

Comment: You could also search for some generic split and join functions that would make the job very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table (I use TITLE_CASE_EXCEPTION as my example) with a column EXCEPTION
Then it is data driven from there.

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[GUI].[fn_TITLE_CASE]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
        DROP FUNCTION [GUI].[fn_TITLE_CASE]
    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION [GUI].[fn_TITLE_CASE] 
        (
        @STRING VARCHAR(MAX)
        )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

        DECLARE @RESET BIT
        DECLARE @_OUT_STRING VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @I INT
        DECLARE @C CHAR(1)

        DECLARE @CASE_LEN INT = 0
        DECLARE @CASE_EXCEPTIONS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        DECLARE @CASE_VALUE VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

        IF @STRING IS NULL
            RETURN NULL
        IF @STRING = ''
            RETURN @STRING

        SELECT @STRING = LOWER(RTRIM(@STRING)), @RESET = 1, @I = 1, @_OUT_STRING = ''

        WHILE (@I <= LEN(@STRING))
        SELECT 
            @C = SUBSTRING(@STRING, @I, 1),
            @_OUT_STRING = @_OUT_STRING + CASE WHEN @RESET = 1 THEN UPPER(@C) ELSE @C END,
            @RESET = CASE WHEN @C LIKE '[a-zA-Z'']' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
            @I = @I + 1

        SELECT @I = 0, @_OUT_STRING = @_OUT_STRING + ' '
        SELECT @CASE_EXCEPTIONS = @CASE_EXCEPTIONS + RTRIM(EXCEPTION) + ',' FROM [LOOKUP].TITLE_CASE_EXCEPTION

        WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @CASE_EXCEPTIONS, @I + 1) > 0 
            BEGIN 
            -- get the delimited word 
            SET @CASE_LEN = CHARINDEX(',', @CASE_EXCEPTIONS, @I + 1) - @I
            SET @CASE_VALUE = SUBSTRING(@CASE_EXCEPTIONS, @I, @CASE_LEN) 

            -- replace it in the original text 
            SET @_OUT_STRING = REPLACE(@_OUT_STRING, ' ' + @CASE_VALUE + ' ', ' ' + @CASE_VALUE + ' ') 

            -- get position of next word 
            SET @I = CHARINDEX(',', @CASE_EXCEPTIONS, @I + @CASE_LEN) + 1 
            END

        RETURN RTRIM(@_OUT_STRING)
    END
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you to reference:

```
declare @s varchar(256) = 'This is a SQL test';
declare @t table (ignore varchar(256) not null);

insert into @t (ignore) values ('SQL');

declare @pos int = 1;
declare @nextpos int;
declare @w varchar(256);

while @pos <= len(@s)
begin
    set @nextpos = charindex(' ', @s + ' ', @pos);
    set @w = substring(@s, @pos, @nextpos - @pos);
    if not exists (select 1 from @t where ignore = @w)
        set @s = stuff(
            @s, @pos, @nextpos - @pos,
            stuff(lower(@w), 1, 1, upper(left(@w, 1)))
        );
    set @pos = @nextpos + 1;
    select @s;
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response. However, I am looking to do the following. Once the fonts have been converted to the proper case, I want to feed the resulting string to a exceptions table with one column as the sub string that needs to be changed and with another column as the resulting string. That way I don't have to mention the exceptions in the function but can call the exceptions table from within the function. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: @user6562697 If you want to do it this way then what was the purpose of posting the function above in the first place? And don't you still have the same problem of splitting the proper-cased string into smaller tokens? Mine was just a sample way to approach it. I think there's a lot in there for you to explore.

Comment: Agree. There is a lot to explore. The function I posted was my way of dealing with the exceptions that occurred in the names contained in the column. But for long term, I don't want to edit the function every time but rather call a table from the function itself for the exceptions and see how that goes. Thanks

Comment: @user6562696 Don't you see where I referenced a table in my example for a list of exceptions?

Comment: @ shawnt00 - Thanks. Yes, I was able to locate it. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original request.. set up a table "Exceptions" with a single column ConcatList of type nvarchar (100) and add the exceptions to this table... then create a view with to concatenate them together...

```
    create table exceptions (ConcatList nvarchar(100))

    create view [dbo].vExceptions
    as
     Select distinct
        substring(
        (
            Select ','+ up.ConcatList  AS [text()]
            From exceptions up 
            ORDER BY up.ConcatList
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 4000) [exceptions]

     From exceptions p
```

Here is a slightly enhanced version of the stored procedure from the question.
 (although an admittedly inelegant solution) to account for:

- Lower case words (of, the, an, etc)
- Hhyphenated acronyms
- Exceptions that are immediately preceeded or followed with a dash or comma.

  ```
  alter FUNCTION [dbo].[Business_ProperCase]
       (@Text AS VARCHAR(8000)) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 
  AS 
  BEGIN 
      -- declare some variables 
      DECLARE @Reset BIT; DECLARE @Ret VARCHAR(8000); DECLARE @i INT; 
      DECLARE @c0 CHAR(1); DECLARE @c1 CHAR(1); DECLARE @c2 CHAR(1); 
      DECLARE @CaseLen INT; 
      DECLARE @CaseExceptions VARCHAR(8000); 
      DECLARE @CaseValue VARCHAR(8000); 

      -- Set some default values 
      SELECT @Reset = 1, @i=1, @Ret = ''; 

      -- only apply if all characters are already in uppercase 
      IF (UPPER(@Text)=@Text COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) 
           BEGIN 

                   -- add a leading and trailing space to indicate word delimiters (bol & eol) 
                   SET @Text = ' ' + @Text + ' '; 

                   -- cycle through each character, 
                   -- if non-alpha, uppercase next alpha character. 
                   -- if alpha then lowercase subsequent alphas. 
                   WHILE (@i <= LEN(@Text)) 
                           SELECT 
                                   @c0=SUBSTRING(@Text,@i-2,1), @c1=SUBSTRING(@Text,@i-1,1), @c2=SUBSTRING(@Text,@i,1), 
                                   @Ret = @Ret + CASE WHEN @Reset=1 THEN UPPER(@c2) ELSE LOWER(@c2) END, 
                                   @Reset = CASE WHEN @c0 = ' ' AND @c1 = 'M' AND @c2 = 'c' THEN 1 
                                                 WHEN @c0 = ' ' AND @c1 IN ('D', 'I', 'O') AND @c2 = '''' THEN 1 
                                                 WHEN @c2 LIKE '[a-zA-Z'']' THEN 0               -- Apply LOWER to any character after alphas or apostrophes 
                                                  ELSE 1                                         -- Apply UPPER to any character after symbols/punctuation 
                                            END, 
                                   @i = @i +1 

                   -- add a trailing space in case the previous rule changed this. 
                   SET @Ret = @Ret + ' '; 

                   -- custom exceptions: this search is case-insensitive and will 
                   -- replace the word to the case as it is written in the list. 
                   -- NOTE: this list has to end with a comma! 
                   SELECT @i=0, @CaseLen=0, 
                           @CaseExceptions = exceptions from vExceptions

  --Want to create a table for these exceptions and call them from this function 
                   -- Loop through exception cases 
                   WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @CaseExceptions, @i+1)>0 
                           BEGIN 
                                   -- get the delimited word 
                                   SET @CaseLen = CHARINDEX(',', @CaseExceptions, @i+1) - @i 
                                   SET @CaseValue = SUBSTRING(@CaseExceptions, @i, @CaseLen) 
                                   if (@CaseValue = 'OF' or @CaseValue = 'AND' or @CaseValue ='THE' or @CaseValue='FOR')
                                   begin
                                       --replace with lower case 'of', 'and', 'the', 'for'
                                       SET @Ret = REPLACE(@Ret, ' '+@CaseValue+' ', ' '+lower(@CaseValue)+' ') 
                                   end
                                   else
                                   begin  
                                      if (CHARINDEX(' '+ @CaseValue +' ', @Ret)>0 )
                                      begin
                                           -- replace it in the original text 
                                           SET @Ret = REPLACE(@Ret, ' '+@CaseValue+' ', ' '+@CaseValue+' ') 
                                      end
                                      else if (CHARINDEX(' '+@CaseValue+',', @Ret)>0 )
                                      begin
                                          --replace text (with no spaces around it)
                                          SET @Ret = REPLACE(@Ret, ' '+@CaseValue+',', ' '+@CaseValue+',') 
                                      end
                                      else if (CHARINDEX(' '+@CaseValue+'-', @Ret)>0 )
                                      begin
                                          --replace text (with no spaces around it)
                                          SET @Ret = REPLACE(@Ret, ' '+@CaseValue+'-', ' '+@CaseValue+'-') 
                                      end
                                      else if (CHARINDEX('-'+@CaseValue+' ', @Ret)>0 )
                                      begin
                                          --replace text (with no spaces around it)
                                          SET @Ret = REPLACE(@Ret, '-'+@CaseValue+' ', '-'+@CaseValue+' ') 
                                      end
                                      else if (CHARINDEX(','+@CaseValue+' ', @Ret)>0 )
                                      begin
                                          --replace text (with no spaces around it)
                                          SET @Ret = REPLACE(@Ret, ','+@CaseValue+' ', '-'+@CaseValue+' ') 
                                      end
                                   end

                                   -- get position of next word 
                                   SET @i = CHARINDEX(',', @CaseExceptions, @i+@CaseLen) +1 
                           END 

                   -- remove any leading and trailing spaces 
                   SET @Ret = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Ret)); 

                   -- capitalize first character of data irrespective of previous rules 
                   SET @Ret = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Ret,1,1)) + SUBSTRING(@Ret,2,LEN(@Ret)); 

           END 
      ELSE 
       BEGIN 
                   -- return the string unaffected if it is not in uppercase 
                   SET @Ret=@Text 
           END 

      RETURN @Ret 
   END
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table (I use `ExceptionsTable` as my example) with a column `WordExcepts`. Then add the following after your last `DECLARE` at the top of the page:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000);

SET @sql = 'N select WordExcepts from ExceptionsTable'
```

Then down below adjust your exceptions to be:

```
@CaseExceptions = @sql
```

Just add to your table as needed and they get filtered out of the function.