# T-SQL - Update first letter in each word of a string that are not 'or', 'of' or 'and' to uppercase. Lowercase 'or', 'of' or 'and' if found

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given the below table and data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
  (
     ID           INT,
     Code         INT,
     PDescription VARCHAR(2000)
  )

INSERT INTO #Temp
            (ID,
             Code,
             PDescription)
VALUES      (1,0001,'c and d, together'),
            (2,0002,'equals or Exceeds $27.00'),
            (3,0003,'Fruit Evaporating Or preserving'),
            (4,0004,'Domestics And domestic Maintenance'),
            (5,0005,'Bakeries and cracker')

SELECT *
FROM   #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Output:

```
ID  Code    PDescription
1   1       c and d, together
2   2       equals or Exceeds $27.00
3   3       Fruit Evaporating Or preserving
4   4       Domestics And domestic Maintenance
5   5       Bakeries and cracker
```

I need a way to achieve the below update to the description field:

```
ID  Code    PDescription
1   1       C and D, Together
2   2       Equals or Exceeds $27.00
3   3       Fruit Evaporating or Preserving
4   4       Domestics and Domestic Maintenance
5   5       Bakeries and Cracker
```

[image]

Comment: Possible in TSQL but much more straightforward using the CLR.

Comment: For one thing, you would need to set the collation to CS instead of CI (Case Sensitive vs Case Insensitive). See Sys.fn_helpcollations

Comment: But as everyone is upvoting here(me included) use another method if you can. SQL is better with holistic values anyways.

Comment: I posted this answer just last month: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255698/proper-title-case-a-column-with-exceptions-table-in-sql-server/38259672#38259672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function is not the most elegant of solutions but should do what you want.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ToProperCase](@textValue AS NVARCHAR(2000))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @reset BIT;
    DECLARE @properCase NVARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE @index INT;
    DECLARE @character NCHAR(1);

    SELECT @reset = 1, @index=1, @properCase = '';

    WHILE (@index <= len(@textValue))
    BEGIN

        SELECT  @character= substring(@textValue,@index,1),
                @properCase = @properCase + CASE WHEN @reset=1 THEN UPPER(@character) ELSE LOWER(@character) END,
                @reset = CASE WHEN @character LIKE N'[a-zA-Z\'']' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                @index = @index +1

    END

    SET @properCase = N' ' + @properCase + N' ';

    SET @properCase = REPLACE(@properCase, N' And ', N' and ');
    SET @properCase = REPLACE(@properCase, N' Or ', N' or ');
    SET @properCase = REPLACE(@properCase, N' Of ', N' of ');

    RETURN RTRIM(LTRIM(@properCase))

END
```

Example use:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
  (
     ID           INT,
     Code         INT,
     PDescription VARCHAR(2000)
  )

INSERT INTO #Temp
            (ID,
             Code,
             PDescription)
VALUES      (1,0001, N'c and d, together and'),
            (2,0002, N'equals or Exceeds $27.00'),
            (3,0003, N'Fruit Evaporating Or preserving'),
            (4,0004, N'Domestics And domestic Maintenance'),
            (5,0005, N'Bakeries and cracker')


SELECT ID, Code, dbo.ToProperCase(PDescription) AS [Desc]
FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

If you want to convert your text to proper case before inserting into table, then simply call function as follow:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp
            (ID,
             Code,
             PDescription)
VALUES      (1,0001, dbo.ToProperCase( N'c and d, together and')),
            (2,0002, dbo.ToProperCase( N'equals or Exceeds $27.00')),
            (3,0003, dbo.ToProperCase( N'Fruit Evaporating Or preserving')),
            (4,0004, dbo.ToProperCase( N'Domestics And domestic Maintenance')),
            (5,0005, dbo.ToProperCase( N'Bakeries and cracker'))
```

Comment: Thank you Edmond, I am stepping through the code now to better understand it and test it with my data.

Comment: Edmond, This works wonderfully, however, i'm catching one issue:
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
  (
     ID           INT,
     Code         INT,
     PDescription VARCHAR(2000)
  )

INSERT INTO #Temp
            (ID,
             Code,
             PDescription)
VALUES      (1,0001,'1 is ≤ 2')


SELECT ID, Code, dbo.ToProperCase(PDescription) AS [Desc]
FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp

ID Code Desc
1 1        1 Is = 2

It is flipping the less than equal to, to just equals. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JackalSnacks I believe the issue has something to do with Unicode to ASCII conversion. I am doing a quick test to see if this is indeed the case.

Comment: I should have noted the table meta i am working with and have said there would be some special character. Sorry about that.

Column_name Type Computed Length Prec Scale Nullable TrimTrailingBlanks FixedLenNullInSource Collation
Description nvarchar no 2000             yes (n/a) (n/a) SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: @JackalSnacks No worries, I have updated the function to make use of Unicode characters instead of ASCII. Be sure to prefix all string literals with the Unicode string indicator (example N'1 is ≤ 2').

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks so much!

Comment: Can we do apostrophe handling?
 'I guess that's enough'
OUT:
'I Guess That'S Enough'

Answer (score 1):

If you fancied going the SQL CLR route the function could look something like

```cs
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    //One or more "word characters" or apostrophes
    private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex("[\\w']+");

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString ProperCase(SqlString subjectString)
    {
        string resultString = null;

        if (!subjectString.IsNull)
        {
            resultString = _regex.Replace(subjectString.ToString().ToLowerInvariant(),
                (Match match) =>
                {
                    var word = match.Value;
                    switch (word)
                    {
                        case "or":
                        case "of":
                        case "and":
                            return word;
                        default:
                            return char.ToUpper(word[0]) + word.Substring(1);
                    }
                });
        }

        return new SqlString(resultString);
    }
}
```

Doubtless there may be Globalization issues in the above but it should do the job for English text.

You could also investigate [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx) but that still leaves you needing to handle your exceptions.

Comment: This is also great, saving this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dramatically modified version of my Proper UDF.   The good news is you may be able to process the entire data-set in **ONE SHOT** rather than linear.

> **Take note of @OverR (override)**

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,Code int,PDescription varchar(150))
Insert into @Table values
(1,1,'c and d, together'),
(2,2,'equals or Exceeds $27.00'),
(3,3,'Fruit Evaporating Or preserving'),
(4,4,'Domestics And domestic Maintenance'),
(5,5,'Bakeries and cracker')

-- Generate Base Mapping Table - Can be an Actual Table
Declare @Pattn table (Key_Value varchar(25));Insert into @Pattn values (' '),('-'),('_'),(','),('.'),('&'),('@'),(' Mc'),(' O''')  -- ,(' Mac')
Declare @Alpha table (Key_Value varchar(25));Insert Into @Alpha values ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('X')
Declare @OverR table (Key_Value varchar(25));Insert Into @OverR values (' and '),(' or '),(' of ')
Declare @Map Table (MapSeq int,MapFrom varchar(25),MapTo varchar(25))
Insert Into @Map
Select MapSeq=1,MapFrom=A.Key_Value+B.Key_Value,MapTo=A.Key_Value+B.Key_Value From @Pattn A Join @Alpha B on 1=1
Union All
Select MapSeq=99,MapFrom=A.Key_Value,MapTo=A.Key_Value From @OverR A

-- Convert Base Data Into XML
Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select KeyID=ID,String=+' '+lower(PDescription)+' ' from @Table For XML RAW)

-- Convert XML to varchar(max) for Global Search & Replace 
Declare @String varchar(max)
Select @String = cast(@XML as varchar(max))
Select @String = Replace(@String,MapFrom,MapTo) From @Map Order by MapSeq

-- Convert Back to XML
Select @XML = cast(@String as XML)

-- Generate Final Results
Select KeyID     = t.col.value('@KeyID', 'int')
      ,NewString = ltrim(rtrim(t.col.value('@String', 'varchar(150)')))
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') AS t (col)
 Order By 1
```

Returns

```
KeyID   NewString
1       C and D, Together
2       Equals or Exceeds $27.00
3       Fruit Evaporating or Preserving
4       Domestics and Domestic Maintenance
5       Bakeries and Cracker
```

Comment: This is also great!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need functions and temporary objects. Take a look at this query:

```
WITH Processor AS
(
    SELECT ID, Code, 1 step,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),'') done,
           LEFT(PDescription, CHARINDEX(' ', PDescription, 0)-1) process,
           SUBSTRING(PDescription, CHARINDEX(' ', PDescription, 0)+1, LEN(PDescription)) waiting
    FROM #temp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Code, step+1,
           done+' '+CASE WHEN process IN ('and', 'or', 'of') THEN LOWER(process) ELSE UPPER(LEFT(process, 1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(process, 2, LEN(process))) END,
           CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', waiting, 0)>0 THEN LEFT(waiting, CHARINDEX(' ', waiting, 0)-1) ELSE waiting END,
           CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', waiting, 0)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(waiting, CHARINDEX(' ', waiting, 0)+1, LEN(waiting)) ELSE NULL END FROM Processor
    WHERE process IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT ID, Code, done PSDescription FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY step DESC) RowNum FROM Processor
) Ordered
WHERE RowNum=1
ORDER BY ID
```

It produces desired result as well. You can `SELECT * FROM Processor` to see all steps executed.